How can I make a formal rule where I can see how many of my courses will overlap at any given time?
I have start and end dates on my google sheet but I need to make a formula that will show me how many classes will overlap, is there a way to see them all at once?
I haven't tried much really. Not sure how to use formulas.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19k4s104TdksRmIG0vbMjIA1q9R-6IGAcSXXyf0MS3Ek/edit?usp=sharing

the formula is dependent on how the data is presented

Here is the sheet, I have course convene date and graduation date. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19k4s104TdksRmIG0vbMjIA1q9R-6IGAcSXXyf0MS3Ek/edit?usp=sharing

Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide more details on your question. Though we assume that convene means start date and end date does equate to graduation. Can you provide more clarity how do you want this data to be displayed. Including expected results in sheets that are created manually this way the community will have better insight over your project.

Computing overlap at any given time
Assuming the start date is the CONVENE DATE and the end date is the GRADUATE DATE, The 8 WEEK MARK represents the date started.
You can use the following formula to perform calculations based on the CONVENE DATE, 8 WEEK MARK, and GRADUATE DATE:
Formula used:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E2:E - D2:D) - (F2:F - D2:D) < 0, 0, (E2:E - D2:D) - (F2:F - D2:D)))

Sample Output


To identify overlaps, set up a Conditional Formatting Rule where the format is applied if the value is greater than 0. This rule will highlight the cell in red when an overlap occurs.
Conditional Formatting



Reference:

ARRAYFORMULA
IF function

